# Travis cannot pull from github repository using token

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I have created a github token in order to auto-deploy using travis-ci.

I'm using this token in my local environment to test it. This is what I do:

```
mkdir out && cd out
git init
git remote add origin https://$USERNAME:$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/$USERNAME/$PROJECT
git pull --all
```

This works like a charm in my own computer, but, when this is executed in travis the only output I get is the following:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/travis/build/$USERNAME/$PROJECT/out/.git/
Fetching origin
remote: Not found
fatal: repository 'https://[secure]@github.com/$USERNAME/$PROJECT/' not found
error: Could not fetch origin
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason, but the url must end with `.git`

Broken URL: `https://username:token@github.com/username/project`

Fixed URL..: `https://username:token@github.com/username/project.git`